# ios change label width at run time objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I made a collection view contain a label, the number of label is random from 1 to 3.

How can i change the width for this label, If the label appear is one make its width cover the phone. If tow label make them half and half of phone size, and same if three ?

Comment: use TextView instead of UIlable. and use resizable view for make it size chagne run time.

Answer (score 1):

as i understand your problem  you want to grow up the size of label's based on random number which fit in screen. i just tried it dynamically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    //getting random number between 1 to 3
    int randomNumber =[self generateRandomNumberBetweenMin:1 Max:3];

    //Finding height of each label
    CGFloat widthOfLabel=self.view.frame.size.width/randomNumber;

    //create number's of label based on random number
    for (int i=0; i<randomNumber; i++) {

        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*widthOfLabel, 20, widthOfLabel, 20 )];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
    }


}

//generate random numbers within range
-(int)generateRandomNumberBetweenMin:(int)min Max:(int)max
{
    return ( (arc4random() % (max-min+1)) + min );
}
```